# DART TOOK TOO LONG TO CONNECT TO THE EMULATROR ON VS CODE

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

[image]

I tried to run dart on vs code via emulator, but somehow it took so long to run, ended up  like the picture.I noticed when I finished setup the dart on vscode, a notification bar popped out on the bottom right says "Flutter sdk is invalid" something like that, then I deleted the flutter path in json